# Reverse or invert regex matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have seen and read several posts about negative matching, i.e. using a "not" operator, but I am looking for something slightly different. I would like to match and replace, but using a "reversed selection" for it.

I'll use a metaphor to try and explain:

Think of a word processing document. When you use "search and replace" you can in some software get highlights for all matches in the document. With regex, this would of course be the matches, and I could replace them with anything I please. BUT what if I want to replace *everything else* with some phrase.

Imagine I have a list of allowed words, which for the sake of simplicity right now contains only one word which is "and" (I'm very picky) and I want to replace everything that is not an allowed word with the string "(censored)".

If the input is "I am nice and friendly and I like to wear ninja outfits" then the output should be "(censored) and (censored) and (censored)".

The question is of a general nature, but I mainly use C# myself and if I get to implement this, it will most likely be using Regex in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I will try all of these interesting approaches. I'm adding this comment to let you know that it will be a while before I get to test, but do not mistake the lack of feedback from me as me being ungrateful or not caring. : )

Comment: Thanks for your replies, they were all useful and I learned something from each one of them. The one from Wiktor was easy for me to use, and it behaved best (regarding my non specified ideas) when I threw some more tricky examples on it, such as starting the input with "and". 
I love SO on days like these, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach based on a `Regex.Split` with a pattern featuring a captured group for a whole word `and`:

```
var str = "I am nice and friendly and I like to wear ninja outfits";
var rx = new Regex(@"(\band\b)");
var res = rx.Split(str).Select(x => x == "and" ? x : // Keep "and"
          !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) ?            // If x is not null or empty
               "<censured>" : "")              // Replace with <censured>, else emtpy string
          .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", res));
```

Output: `<censured>and<censured>and<censured>`

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/n9c9Hq)

Answer (score 1):

You could capture all the text around "and" with a regex like this `((.\*?)(and))|((.\*)$)` using the `/g` option. This would match all the pieces of text before the and's and the last piece of text after the last and. You would then have to process the match groups to replace the correct parts and leaving the and in place:
https://regex101.com/r/dP4yG6/1

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
(.+?)(\s?and\s?|$)
```

and replace with

```
(censored)$2
```

[Check it out here](https://regex101.com/r/wS6vL7/2),

Comment: Revisiting old questions. This answer is super nice, there's just one edge case issue: If the text starts with "and", that leading "and" is removed.